# How to match strings between quotation marks in a better way

Tags: java, json, regex, string, match

I have a JSON file that I need to read and load without using any external libraries, so my best bet is using regex. My current regex for finding the string is `\"\\.*\"` but for some reason, the entire JSON file is matched, so I get `"FIRST":"Galina98", "LAST":"Murray856", "SUFFIX":""` instead of just `"FIRST"` why could this be happening? I thought that the dot should escape the newline character.

Or is there any better regex? My main issue is that I want to have two patterns, one for the words on the left, and second for the words on the right, such as `\"\\.*\":` and `:\"\\.*\"` respectively, how can I do that?

Comment: Try `\"([^\"]*)\":\"([^\"]*)\"`

Comment: thanks omar, this works but it gives me  code ```"FIRST":"Jorge"``` instead, I would like to have 1 regex for just ```"FIRST``` and 2nd regex for just ```"Jorge"```

Comment: I guess you can do just `\"[^\"]*\"` then, if you don't care which is which.

Comment: Your regex matches a quote, a literal dot then a quote. ie `"."`. Before doing anything else remove the double backslashes entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Use reluctant quantifier `*?` instead of greedy one `*`; and capturing groups for key and value `()` like in: `"(.*?)":"(.*?)"`. Use `Matcher#find()` to search for every occurrence like in:

```
var text = """
           "FIRST":"Galina98", \
           "LAST":"Murray856", \
           "SUFFIX":"" \
           """;
var pattern = Pattern.compile("\"(.*?)\":\"(.*?)\"");
var matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
while (matcher.find()) {
    var key = matcher.group(1);
    var value = matcher.group(2);
    ...
}
```

`(.*?)` is a capturing group for `.*?`

`.*?` will match smallest number of any character (so to match rest of expression) - `*?` is a *reluctant quantifier* since it tries to match the shortest sequence possible; as opposed to `*`, the *greedy quantifier*, that tries to match as much as possible

---

A better/faster approach, as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66616881/how-to-match-strings-between-quotation-marks-in-a-better-way/66617253#comment117762971_66617253) by Omar Si is using `[^"]*`, that is, matching as many characters as possible that are not `"`.

So the Java pattern would be

```
var pattern = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\":\"([^\"]*)\"");
```

---

Be aware that regular expression (alone) is not the best tool for parsing (e.g. having double quotes inside the key or value; line breaks; ...)

Comment: Please note that using `[^\"]*` is more efficient than `.*?` because `.*?` will match character by character while `[^\"]*` will just match everything that is not a quote at once.

Comment: @OmarSi *all* processing/matching by regex engines is character by character.

Comment: @Bohemian Maybe I misspoke. `.*?` would match as little as possible, meaning it will start from the first char after the quote and try to match char by char until it finds the other quote. While `[^\"]*` will just match everything that is not a quote at once, reducing the number of steps needed.

Comment: You can compare the number of steps here https://regex101.com/r/DgmQCs/1 vs https://regex101.com/r/DgmQCs/2

Comment: sorry, my previous test was not the best. I changed to exclude compilation of pattern, creation of matcher and reading of groups; now just 4 times `find()` on text given by Samuel V (also changed warmup and iteration count) Result: Greedy is almost twice as fast: `greedy: 2242,901; reluct: 1181,724`